# How to determine the Mock and injectMock objects in mockito?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I am beginner with Mockito  framework, and i have some problems in determining the mocked and injected mocks objects, Actually I have the following structure in my project.

```
//WebService Interface

Interface WebService{
    @Gateway(...)
    public x call1(parameters);
}

//Class that implements another interface

Class A implements interfaceA{

@Autowired
WebService WS;

    public void M1(){
    .....
        WS.call1(parameters);
    .....
    }

}

//Test Class
@Mock
@Autowired
WebService WS;

@InjectMock
@Autowired
A a;

@Before
setup(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
@Rollback(true)
@Transactional
public void Test() {

    when(WS.call1(parameters)).thenReturn(x);
    actualResult = a.M1();
    assertNotNull(actualResult);
    verify(WS, Mockito.times(1)).call1(parameters);
}
```

Are the Mocked and injected mock objects chosen correctly?
And if yes, i keep getting this exception message:

Wanted but not invoked:
WS.call1(
    ........
);
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `@Mock` and `@Autowired` together. This doesn't make sense. You either mock or autowire your beans. Remove Autowiring

```
@Mock
WebService WS;

@InjectMock
A a;
```